# How to play audio stream chunks recorded with WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, webrtc, web-audio-api

I'm trying to create an experimental application that streams audio in real time from `client 1` to `client 2`.

So following some tutorials and questions about the same subject, I used **WebRTC** and **binaryjs**. So far this is what I get

1- `Client 1` and `Client 2` have connected to BinaryJS to send/receive data chunks.

2- `Client 1` used WebRTC to record audio and gradually send it to BinaryJS

3- `Client 2` receives the chunks and try to play them.

Well I'm getting an error in the last part. This is the error message I get:

> Uncaught RangeError: Source is too large
>
> at Float32Array.set (native)

And this is the code:

**Client 1**

```
var WSClient;
var AudioStream;

function load(){
    var session = {
        audio: true,
        video: false
    };

    var recordRTC = null;

    navigator.getUserMedia(session, startRecording, onError);
    WSClient = new BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9001');
    WSClient.on('open',function(){
        console.log('client opened')
        AudioStream = WSClient.createStream();
    })
}

function startRecording(stream){
    var context = new AudioContext();
    var audio_input = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
    var buffer_size = 2048;

    var recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(buffer_size, 1, 1);

    recorder.onaudioprocess = function(e){
        console.log('chunk')
        var left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
        AudioStream.write(left);
    };

    audio_input.connect(recorder);
    recorder.connect(context.destination);
}
```

**Client 2**

```
var WSClient;
var audioContext;
var sourceNode;

function load(){
    audioContext = new AudioContext();
    sourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource();
    sourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination);

    sourceNode.start(0);

    WSClient = new BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9001');

    WSClient.on('open',function(){
        console.log('client opened');
    });

    WSClient.on('stream', function(stream, meta){
        // collect stream data
        stream.on('data', function(data){
            console.log('received chunk')
            var integers = new Int16Array(data);
            var audioBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(1, 2048, 4410);
            audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(integers); //appearently this is where the error occurs
            sourceNode.buffer = audioBuffer;
        });
    });
}
```

**Server**

```
var wav = require('wav');
var binaryjs = require('binaryjs');

var binaryjs_server = binaryjs.BinaryServer;

var server = binaryjs_server({port: 9001});

server.on('connection', function(client){
    console.log('server connected');

    var file_writter = null;

    client.on('stream', function(stream, meta){
        console.log('streaming', server.clients)
        //send to other clients
        for(var id in server.clients){
            if(server.clients.hasOwnProperty(id)){
                var otherClient = server.clients[id];
                if(otherClient != client){
                    var send = otherClient.createStream(meta);
                    stream.pipe(send);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    client.on('close', function(stream){
        console.log('client closed')
        if(file_writter != null) file_writter.end();
    });
});
```

The error occurs here:

```
audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(integers);
```

So I have two questions:

Is it possible to send the chunks I captured in `client 1` and then reproduce them in `client 2`?

What is the deal with the error I'm having?

Thanks guys!

**@edit 1**

Since i'm getting code snippets from other questions I'm still trying to understand it. I commented the line in `client 2` code that creates an `Int16Array` and I now get a different error (but I don't know which version of the code is more correct):

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'buffer' property on 'AudioBufferSourceNode': Cannot set buffer after it has been already been set

Probably because I'm setting it everytime I get a new chunk of data.

Answer (score 0):

The DOMException about `AudioBufferSourceNode` means you need to create a new `AudioBufferSourceNode` for every new `Audiobuffer` that you're creating.  So something like

`sourceNode = new AudioBufferSourceNode(audioContext, {buffer: audioBuffer})`

And an `AudioBuffer` has `Float32Array`s.  You need to convert your
`Int16Array` to a `Float32Array` before assigning it to an
`AudioBuffer`.  Probably good enough to divide everything by 32768.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. But is this a correct approach? Creating a new source everytime i receive a new chunk?

Comment: Given the current code, yes, I think this is the only way. It's not great. I'm not really familiar with WebRTC and such, but there might be other ways where your server could just stream data to, say, an audio element that you could hook up to WebAudio.

Comment: @RaymondToy, yes, to use WebRTC properly, you've got to use the PeerConnection API. Sending raw audio buffers in javascript isn't even a WebRTC. (and doing any performance-demanding thing like that in js is just immediately wrong)

Comment: dividing by 32768 did not give me a good quality on chrome , you need to convert your raw file to a wav file by adding a header and use decodeAudioData method of web audio API

Comment: Sticking a wav file header in front of the raw data and then calling decodeAudioData is wasteful.  You have the raw data so adding a header doesn't help and calling decodeAudioData doesn't really give you anything extra, except you get float data out.  You could have done this with the raw data.  After all, you have to stick the right header on and if you know that, you know how to convert the raw data to floats.