# Play audio from partial response and save the buffer once complete

Tags: javascript, streaming, html5-audio, web-audio-api

**Background**

I am writing a service to serve static audio files in chunks to support a fluent experience for users with lower bandwidth. Once the file is fully streamed (the chunk sequence is linear, users won't be able to "jump" the range), I want to save the file into a local cache (using localforage, but that's not part of this question) to later load cached files from there and to save bandwidth.

**Problem**

It is with my current state of knowledge / code / tools only possible to do one of the following:

**A) Stream the audio with [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement)**

```
const audio = new Audio()
audio.src = url
audio.preload = 'auto'
audio.load()
```

The HTML5 audio takes internally care of the partial response, working fine itself but I am not able to access the underlying buffer to save the file, once fully loaded. Thus, I won't be able to cache the file locally without downloading it separately (in another request).

**B) Download / [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) the file as a whole, then play it**

```
fetch(url, options) // set content header to array buffer
  .then((response) => {
    var blob = new Blob([response.value], { type: 'audio/mp3' })
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    const audio = new Audio()
    audio.src = url
    audio.play()
  })
```

This gives me the access to the data so I can cache it for offline reuse. But I loose the streaming option, which makes it nearly impossible to play larger files without ages of waiting.

**C) Using a custom loader and play each chunk using WebAudio API**

Since A and B were not sufficient, I wrote a [custom loader](http://jsfiddle.net/o2L3n5az/), that loads the chunks (which is working fine), and dispatches an event with the current chunk (as ArrayBuffer) as data. It also dispatches another event on end, that returns all the chunks, so I can create a blob from it:

```
const chunkSize = 2048
const audioContext = new AudioContext()
const loader = new StreamLoader(url,  {step: chunkSize})

loader.on(StreamLoader.event.response, (data) => {
  // data.response is of type ArrayBuffer
  const floats = new Float32Array(data.response)
  const audioBuffer = audioContext.createBuffer(1, chunkSize, 4410)
  audioBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(floats)
  const sourceNode = new AudioBufferSourceNode(audioContext, {buffer: audioBuffer})
  sourceNode.connect(audioContext.destination)
  sourceNode.start(0)
})

loader.once(StreamLoader.event.complete, (data) => {
  const blob = new Blob(Object.values(data), {type: fileType})
  const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  const audio = new Audio();
  audio.src = url;
  audio.play();
})

loader.load()
```

Problem here is that it produces only weird loud noise. However, playing from the blob, once completed, works fine.

I am aware of the issue, that the header needs to be present in order to decode the audio correctly, so I am curious how the HTMLAudioElement or MediaStream actually internally resolve this.

**D) Using [MediaStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream) or [MediaRecorder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/MediaRecorder) with custom loader**

Since I am not recording from a local device, I did not got any of these  to work with streaming the chunks, that I loaded using xhr. Are they restricted to be used with local media sources?

**E) Using tools like Howler, SoundManager, SoundJS.**

I found the above mentioned tools, but unfortunately came back to issue A or B using them.

**Expected Solution**

What I expect to find is a solution, that allows me to play the audio from stream (partial response) and to access the buffered data in order to cache it.

**Related SO resources:**

[How to play audio stream chunks recorded with WebRTC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47274120/how-to-play-audio-stream-chunks-recorded-with-webrtc)

[HTML5 record audio to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16413063/html5-record-audio-to-file)

[HTML Audio element source from cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48491950/html-audio-element-source-from-cache)

Comment: Think you should take a look at using Service Worker and the [Cache](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache) api. it's possible to download a resource, clone it and pipe it to both the cache and the response (Audio) at the same time. [sw-toolbox](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/sw-toolbox/) is also pretty cool

Comment: if service worker is not an option (wish is sad cuz option A + service worker are meant for this), then you need to use fetch api and get a readableStream from `response.body`

Comment: Hi thank you for the response. Serviceworker is unfortunately not an option but the fetch solution would be interesting. Could you elaborate on that? How would you pass the readableStream to the `HtmlAudioElement` so that it can start playing as soon as possible / after the first N chunks?

Comment: Thanks for this code: var blob = new Blob([response.value], { type: 'audio/mp3' }) var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)

Comment: Why this code http://jsfiddle.net/o2L3n5az/ gives me this error:
Uncaught RangeError: byte length of Float32Array should be a multiple of 4
    at new Float32Array (<anonymous>)
    at StreamLoader.<anonymous>